# Encoding a URL in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, haml

`.agency{style: "background-image: url(#{image_path "transport-logos/#{service.agency_name}.png"})"}`

When `service.agency_name` contains spaces, I get invalid resource names, such as `transport-logos/some name.png` instead of `transport-logos/some%20name.png`.

How do I convert spaces to %20 in HAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
URI.encode("some name")
```

will give `some%20name`

Change your code as below,

```
.agency{style: "background-image: url(#{image_path "transport-logos/#{URI.encode(service.agency_name)}.png"})"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CGI.escape` method

```
.agency{style: "background-image: url(#{image_path "transport-logos/#{CGI.escape(service.agency_name)}.png"})"}
```